# CNAME in WHM - Stopping my domain name being appended automatically?

Tags: dns, cname, whm

One of the requirements is to add a CNAME = example.com

I am attempting to do this via WHM but the problem is that it is auto-appending my domain name after the 'example.com' entry so when I save the record gets saved as example.com.mydomainname.com

I have tried entering the record with a full stop after it as example.com. and also with a " " space after the full stop but it still automatically appends.

How can I stop the auto-append of my domain name to a CNAME??

Comment: you can't add a cname to a domain that you don't control

Comment: *One of the requirements* -- one of the requirements of what?

Comment: Requirement of: https://docs.gitbook.com/hosting/custom-domains/dns-configuration

Comment: Daniel has the right answer.  The only names you can add are subdomains of a domain you control.  You can add "docs.mydomainname.com".  You can't add "learn.microsoft.com".